# Base vs Structure vs Substructure

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between these three terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *base* is the start of something, or the home of something.

A *structure* is something that has parts that are connected together that can be replaced or customized.

A *substructure* would be a structure that's part of a bigger structure.

Bases can be structures, and structures can be bases.  A base is unlikely to be a substructure, but might have one or more substructures.